# Calling secure webservice using CXF and Camel

Tags: apache-camel, cxf

I am trying to call a SOAP webservice on an https URL, where client authentification (SSL) is required.

Right now I am configuring my camel context using spring (switched away from blueprint) and creating my endpoints using the Camel CXF component with jetty as transport.

I can't find any good examples for this out there. Maybe I should be using http4 in stead of Jetty. I was trying to set up some Camel sslContextParameters, but I can't see this working with CXF and/or Jetty.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if you're invoking a SOAP service, you need to use the camel-cxf component, not camel-cxfrs. The latter is for REST endpoints.

You say that client authorization is required, but you don't specify which type. Given that you talk about SSL, I will assume you need to configure both SSL and HTTP Auth.

For SSL, have a look at: https://camel.apache.org/camel-configuration-utilities.html and 
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Security_Guide/files/CamelCXF-SecureClient.html.

For HTTP Basic Auth, have a look at the `username` and `password` options here: https://camel.apache.org/cxf.html.

EDIT : 
[RedHat CXF Security Guide 6.1](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.1/pdf/Apache_CXF_Security_Guide/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse-6.1-Apache_CXF_Security_Guide-en-US.pdf)

Comment: You are of course right. It is camel-cxf and not cxfrs I am working with. Thanks for the links. I will have a look at it.

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect your comments above and I will add my resulting spring XML below.

Comment: FYI: The redhat link is dead... Please see [answer] about links in an answer. This is the perfect example of why you should not just include the links.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to raulk i was able to create a working spring configuration for accessing a secure webservice. I used wsdl2java (CXF) to generate the Java code for creating a client endpoint to the service I am calling.

This is my spring configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
       xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
       xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
         http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
         http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
         http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/security.xsd
         http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
       ">

    <!-- My camel routes -->
    <bean id="myClientRoute" class="com.mycompany.myWebserviceClientRouteBuilder"/>

    <!-- Name of conduit must match the target namespace and service name of the @WebService identifier in the autogenerated webservice interface -->
    <http:conduit name="{targetNamespace}WebserviceName.http-conduit">
        <http:tlsClientParameters>
            <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="Test1234">
                <sec:keyStore password="Test1234" type="JKS"
                              resource="classpath:certs/myKeystore.jks" />
            </sec:keyManagers>
            <sec:trustManagers>
                <sec:keyStore password="Test1234" type="JKS"
                              resource="classpath:certs/myTruststore.jks" />
            </sec:trustManagers>
            <sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
                <sec:include>.*_WITH_3DES_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:include>.*_WITH_DES_.*</sec:include>
                <sec:exclude>.*_WITH_NULL_.*</sec:exclude>
                <sec:exclude>.*_DH_anon_.*</sec:exclude>
            </sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
        </http:tlsClientParameters>
    </http:conduit>

    <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="myRemoteWebserviceEndpoint"
                     address="{{HTTPS_ADDRESS_OF_REMOTE_WEBSERVICE_PROPERTYE}}"
                     serviceClass="com.autogenerated.ServiceClassFromWSDL">
    </cxf:cxfEndpoint>

    <camel:camelContext id="myCamelContext">
        <camel:routeBuilder ref="myClientRoute"/>
    </camel:camelContext>

</beans>
```

My Camel route looks like this:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("direct:in")
            //Create SOAP request headers and body
            .bean(RequestGenrator.class, "createRequest")
            //Call webservice
            .to("cxf:bean:myRemoteWebserviceEndpoint?dataFormat=MESSAGE")
            .bean(ResponseHandler.class, "extractResponse");
}
```